# Retrieve adWordsCampaignID from current view in Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

Using only the Analytics API, I've discovered you can pull Adwords data by specifying the **adwordsCampaignID** However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the **adwordsCampaignID** of the current view, or alternately, to get it by filtering on some property of the current view.

I cycle through several dozen domains and need to pull the adwordsCampaignID of each view & insert it into the following function.
a

```
function getAdWords(&$analytics, $profileId) {
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2014-07-01',
       '2014-09-09',
      'ga:adClicks,ga:CTR,ga:impressions', 
      array('dimensions' => 'ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:adwordsAdGroupID,ga:adGroup,ga:keyword','sort' =>
            '-ga:impressions','filters' => 'ga:adwordsCampaignID=='.'8486***','max-results' => '50')

       );
```

}

```
Something along the lines of $results = getAdwordsCampaignID($analytics);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns you can pull AdWords data using only the Google Analytics API (as long as your GA account is joined to the AdWords account).

Can be done like this:

```
function getAdWords(&$analytics, $profileId) {
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2014-07-01',
       '2014-09-09',
      'ga:adClicks,ga:CTR,ga:impressions', 
      array('dimensions' => 'ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:adwordsAdGroupID,ga:adGroup,ga:keyword','sort' =>
            '-ga:impressions','filters' => 'ga:adwordsCampaignID=='.'84*690*','max-results' => '50')

       );

}
```

However, there are limitations. You must have the adWordsCampaignID. As far as I can tell, there is no way to retrieve the adWordsCampaignID of a view using only the GA API. You must join the data between the AdWords + GA APIs using the CustomerID variable.

The Google API Query Explorer is a great help if you are working to implement this.